# Sharing an array between 2 classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I currently have two arrays, 1 in each class, but I am cloning them before displaying the other viewController. So whatever happens e.g. delete an item in one viewController, I clone the array for the other ViewController when it needs it.

What is the best way to make these ViewControllers read and write to the same array? I would like a shared array resource which I can access, modify from the 2 viewControllers, possibly a third, whenever necessary.

How is this done without cloning all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a singleton class which holds the array, then access it through the sharedInstance. I recommend [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) for a review of the various approaches to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is shared only by the two view controllers, just let them point to the same object.

```
@interface FirstViewController {
    //...
    NSMutableArray *arrayData;
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayData;
@end

@interface SecondViewController {
    //...
    NSMutableArray *arrayData;
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayData;
@end
```

And somewhere in the code

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
firstViewController.arrayData = array;
secondViewController.arrayData = array;
[array release];
```

This array conceptually becomes a Model for your design. If the two view controllers perform the same tasks on the data of the array that can be abstracted, consider having a custom class that contains the array and serves as the model class.

Comment: I will have 3 classes accessing the array. One adds objects, the other 2 read and remove objects.

Comment: The same, unless the number of sharers is large, or the sharers are not deterministic (dynamic objects will access the array), or you feel so lazy to implement properties for each of the sharers and would go with a singleton approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good use of the Model-View-Controller paradigm.  Break out the array into the model that both view controllers can access.